# Show column data in excel that matches todays dates, or the current week

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an excel sheet with 15 columns including a date column. Is it possible to copy to another sheet that will show only the columns/data with today's date? Or the week?

(It is difficult to scroll through to find the data each day to find the date.)

Comment: instead of copying, use a filter (and then copy/paste if you have to do it).

Comment: I agree with @gns100. You'll want to apply a filter to your header row (where the titles of your columns live) and then you can either sort (i.e. keep all data visible, but present it in a different way) or filter (i.e. hide rows that don't contain informantion you need). It'll save you a lot of stress and hassle once you get the hang of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I would like to suggest you two different methods.*

**One** is an Array Formula and **Second** is VBA Code, to Filter Records matches the Current Date.

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$4:$D$10, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!$E$4, Sheet1!$A$4:$A$10), ROW(Sheet1!$A$4:$D$10)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!$A$4:$D$10))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")}
```

**NB:**

*E4 is Cell where Today's date is written. Finish the Formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** then drag Right till the required Columns and then Down.*

**If you have huge Data Range better use this VBA Code.**

```
Sub CopyRowWithCurrentDate()

    Dim xRgS As Range, xRgD As Range, xCell As Range
    Dim I As Long, xCol As Long, J As Long
    Dim xVal As Variant

    On Error Resume Next

    Set xRgS = Application.InputBox("Select the Date Column:", "Filter On Date", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)

    If xRgS Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set xRgD = Application.InputBox("Select a destination cell:", "Filter On Date", , , , , , 8)

    If xRgD Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    xCol = xRgS.Rows.Count
    Set xRgS = xRgS(1)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    J = 0
    For I = 1 To xCol
        Set xCell = xRgS.Offset(I - 1, 0)
        xVal = xCell.Value

        If TypeName(xVal) = "Date" And (xVal <> "") And (xVal = Date) Then 'You should manipulate the days you are filtering by typing accurate days!
            xCell.EntireRow.Copy xRgD.Offset(J, 0)
            J = J + 1
        End If

    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = True

End Sub
```

*Hope this Help You.*